# What is prefered type for "_id" column of content providers : int or long?

Tags: android, sqlite

I've came across code in android sources which implicitly check whether some numerical Id for a content provider is of type long or not. Sqlite however seems to have just "INTEGER" type.

So, Should on always use long data type to handle values from "INTEGER" columns in sqlite, just to be safe ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In SQLite, [all integer values have 64 bits](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#storageclasses).
Small values are stored more efficiently in the database file, but that is completely transparent.

So, if it is possible that your `_id` column has more than two billion values, then you should use `long`.

Comment: IOW, it depends on what you put into the column. If yours is the only code that is putting stuff into the column, and you consistently store `int`, you can consistently retrieve `int`.